# How can I set Vuetify v-data-table height to be dynamic?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

[image]

As you can see, I used a `<v-data-table>` which takes all available height. I got this result by adding `height="70vh"` to it, but obviuously this is a workaround: if I change the toolbar height (the one which shows "Devices"), I must update the table height accordingly.

How can I set the height to be dynamic?

**Edit #1**

The goal is to have a table which properly calculates its height by simply doing

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  height="100%"
  fixed-header
  disable-pagination
></v-data-table>
```

To effectively use `height="100%"`, we must explicitly set a height to the tag which is going to wrap our table

```
<template>
  <!-- $vuetify.application stores layout sizes -->
  <v-container :style="{ height: `calc(100vh - ${$vuetify.application.bar}px)` }">
    <!-- table here -->
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Before moving on with the explanation, there's something I'd like to point out. `<v-data-table>`s are rendered like this

```
<div class="v-data-table ...">
  <div class="v-data-table__wrapper">...</div>
  <div class="v-data-footer">...</div>
</div>
```

and when we set the height by doing this `<v-data-table height="100%">`, we are instead setting `v-data-table__wrapper` height. To make everything works as expected, we must set the outer `<div>` height too.

```
<template>
  <v-container :style="{ height: `calc(100vh - ${$vuetify.application.bar}px)` }">
    <v-data-table
      style="height: 100%;"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      height="100%"
      fixed-header
      disable-pagination
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Finally we must subtract the footer height, which is 59px.

```
<!-- Relevant code snippet -->
<v-data-table
  style="height: 100%;"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  height="calc(100% - 59px)"
  fixed-header
  disable-pagination
></v-data-table>
```

While this solution kinda works, there are a couple of things to point out:

1. We are hardcoding the footer height, which is not a good practice.
2. Everything starts to get messier when you add content to slots, like the `#top` one. You must take into consideration its height too.

.

```
<!-- Relevant code snippet -->
<v-data-table
  style="height: 100%;"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :height="`calc(100% - 59px - ${topSlotHeight}px)`"
  fixed-header
  disable-pagination
></v-data-table>
```

If you are looking for a workaround, this implementation might suit you.

Comment: You could try height: calc(100vh - 80px); Or whatever your toolbar height is. A more generic approach would be to use flexgrid css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamic height of table (vuetify)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867308/dynamic-height-of-table-vuetify)

Comment: @DebugDiva more or less.

Comment: @ESP32 could you show me your flexgrid CSS approach?