# How can I vertically center Vuetify v-data-table messages?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

[image]

I'd like to have `No data available` message vertically centered. How can I achieve my goal?

**Edit #1**

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72662030/how-can-i-set-vuetify-v-data-table-height-to-be-dynamic) to better understand how `<v-data-table>` height works.